# particular solution of the given differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with this calculus problem I am very confused about how to go through with this problem!

Find the particular solution of the given differential equation
$$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=−6xe^{y−x^2}$$with $y=12$  when  $x=1$.

Can anyone help walk me through this?

Answer (score 1):

Use separation of variables, note that$$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=−6xe^{y}e^{−x^2}$$or$$e^{-y} \ \text{d}y =−6xe^{−x^2} \ \text{d}x$$Integrate both sides, you will get$$-e^{-y}=3e^{-x^2}+C$$And using the condition $y(1)=12$, find the value of constant $C$ $$-\frac{1}{e^{12}}=\frac{3}{e}+C$$

Comment: what answer did you get? or could you show me your steps?

Comment: Which part is not clear in my solution?

Comment: $-\frac{1}{e^{-12}}$ or $-\frac{1}{e^{12}}$?